# What is the fundamental group of Kontsevich's space of stable maps?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, birational-geometry, mapping-class-groups, gromov-witten-theory

... at least in the case where the target is a rationally connected variety.

This question is a follow-up to question 
[Constructing embedded families of curves with general moduli](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264930/constructing-embedded-families-of-curves-with-general-moduli)
and Jason Starr's suggestion in the comments there.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $\geq 3$ that is separably rationally connected. Fix $g \geq 2$, $r \geq 0$ and sufficiently positive curve class $\beta$. Consider the morphism
$$ \mathcal{F} := (ev,\Phi): \mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta) \to X^r \times \mathcal{M}_{g,r} $$

What can be said about the topological properties of the fiber of $\mathcal{F}$?
(for a general reference to topological properties of fibers of morphism, see : [Structure of fundamental groups arising from smooth projective morphisms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137251/structure-of-fundamental-groups-arising-from-smooth-projective-morphisms))

That is,

1. What conditions do I need to impose to say something about the homotopy type of the general fiber? In particular, what restrictions can I impose to deduce that it is connected and simply connected outside a complex codimension 1 subset of $\mathcal{M}_{g,r} \times X^r$? The motivation for this question is to understand if we can lift classes in $\pi_1^{orb}(\mathcal{M}_{g,r})$ to $\pi_1(\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta))$ using the standard fibration long exact sequence argument.
2. I know the study of the rational connectedness of the fibers (which I guess is kind of an algebraic-geometry analogue of connectedness) of these map plays some kind of a rule in the study of rational connectedness of the target variety. Can somehow provide a reference for a good paper that summerizes what is currently known?
3. Is there a known paper that studies the lift of the orbifold fundemental group of $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}$ in this context? That is, a lift of the MCG to the fundamental group of the Kontsevich moduli space of stable maps?

Comment: For $g$ equal to $0$ and for $r=1$, there is a conjecture of Graeme Segal, refined by Cohen-Jones-Segal, that as $\langle c_1(T_X),\beta \rangle \to \infty$, the homotopy types of the fibers of $\text{ev}:\mathcal{M}_{0,1}(X,\beta) \to X$ converge (in an appropriate sense) to the homotopy type of the space $\text{Hom}_{\text{ptd}}((\mathbf{S}^2,0),(X^\text{an},{x_0})$, the double loop space of $X$.  Segal proved this for $X=\mathbb{P}^n$, and there were many cases proved after that, cf. "Stability for holomorphic spheres and Morse theory" , Cohen, Jones, Segal, and the references therein.

Comment: There are two sources of a nontrivial fundamental group of the space of holomorphic spheres.  First of all, nontrivial elements of $\pi_3(X^{\text{an}})$ give nontrivial elements of $\pi_1$ of the double loop space.  For $X$ Fano, most such elements arise from surjective morphisms $\pi:X\to \mathbb{P}^1$.  Every such morphism factors through a morphism with connected fibers.  By the Rationally Connected Fibration Theorem, there exists a section $s:\mathbb{P}^1\to X$.  Thus, $\pi_3(X^{\text{an}})\to \pi_3(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ is surjective, so the Hopf class in $\pi_3(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ lifts . . .

Comment: . . . The corresponding contribution to the fundamental group of $\mathcal{M}_{0,1}(X,\beta)$ works in the same way: stabilization with respect to $\pi$ defines a morphism $\mathcal{M}_{0,1}(X,\beta) \to \mathcal{M}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^1,\pi_*\beta)$, and the section $s$ defines a section of this (for appropriate $\beta$).  The fundamental group of $\mathcal{M}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^1,e)$ can be understood in terms of monodromy about the boundary components in the simply connected space $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^1,e)$, but it is basically the Hopf class again . . .

Comment: . . . The second source for the fundamental group comes from $H^{2,1}(X)$, i.e., a nontrivial Griffiths intermediate Jacobian $J_1(X)$.  In this case, there is an Abel map $\alpha:\mathcal{M}_{0,1}(X,\beta)\to J_1(X)$, and this is dominant for sufficiently positive $\beta$.  So the nontrivial fundamental group of the complex torus $J_1(X)$ implies that also $\mathcal{M}_{0,1}(X,\beta)$ is nontrivial.  Segal's conjecture implies, more or less, these are the only contributions to the fundamental group as $\beta \to \infty$, cf. the discussion of $\pi_3(X)$ in the book by Griffiths-Morgan.

Comment: @JasonStarr Cool! But my question was actually more in the direction of the high genus case. I was wondering whether or not it makes sense to generalize the results in [Rational Normal Curves on Low Degree Complete Intersections](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.3506) to show that the forgetful map has generically simply connected fibers (and deal with genus $g \geq 2$ curves instead of rational ones.)

Comment: ... or maybe if the target $X$ is a homogeneous variety $G/P$ etc.

Comment: I was looking to do the following: if the morphism $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta)) \to \mathcal{M}_{g,r}$ has connected fibers, then there is a surjective map of fundamental groups. Then its a question of finding a section in order to lift the MCG action to the Kontsevich moduli space ... is that reasonable or am I just being silly?

Comment: For $g\geq 1$, the fibers of $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta)\to X^r \times \mathcal{M}_{g,r}$ will not be simply connected.  For every invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$, for every $r$-pointed genus $g$ curve $(C,p_1,\dots,p_r)$, for every morphism $u:C\to X$, the class of $u^*\mathcal{L}$ defines an element in the Jacobian of $C$.  So the fibers of the forgetful map have nontrivial Abel maps.  You could factor the forgetful map through a universal Abel map to a relative Picard over $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}$ and try to prove that the fibers of that Abel map are simply connected.

Comment: Great! Thanks again. Since I'm probably going to work with the Torelli group instead of the full MCG (so the entire Jacobian bundle can be trivialized over the moduli of curves), I think that's what I'll try and do. What about just connected? (shouldn't that be always true generically?)

Comment: Segal's conjecture says that for $\beta$ sufficiently large, $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta)$ is connected.  Inside of this connected space, the locus of multiple covers of a fixed very free genus $0$ curve gives a subvariety of $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta)$ in the smooth locus and that maps to $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}$ with connected fibers (for $\beta$ sufficiently positive and divisible).  This implies that a general fiber of $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta) \to \mathcal{M}_{g,r}$ is irreducible, cf. Lemma 3.2 of "Low degree complete intersections are rationally simply connected" by de Jong and myself.

Comment: By considering generic deformations of stable maps obtained by glueing a few very free genus $0$ "bubbles" to such multiple covers, that should also work if $\beta$ is not divisible.

Comment: Awesome :-) , I'm gonna go and read it.