# Higher genus Cohen-Jones-Segal's conjecture?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry, mapping-class-groups, gromov-witten-theory

Let $X$ be a projective variety. As I've been told, there is a conjecture (by Cohen-Jones-Segal) which implies that the homotopy type of fibers of the stablization-evaluation morphism 
$$(ev,\Phi):\mathcal{M}_{0,1}(X,\beta) \to X \times \mathcal{M}_{0,1}$$ 
converge to the homotopy type of the double loop space of $X$.

***Question.*** So what about higher genus?

I believe that Segal original paper [The topology of spaces of rational functions](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485890033)
dealt with a genus $g$ Riemann surface and not neccesarily just the genus zero cases. But most of the later papers either have "interesting" target spaces $X \neq \mathbb{CP}^n$ ***or*** higher genus - but not both (at least those I was able to find...)

1. What does the Cohen-Jones-Segal conjecture implies for the homotopy type of fibers 
   $$(ev,\Phi):\mathcal{M}_{g,1}(X,\beta) \to X \times \mathcal{M}_{g}$$ 
   with $g \geq 1$? I assume it should be something like: "the inclusion into the space of differentiable maps from a genus $g$ surface and homology class $\beta$ to $X$ is a weak homotopy equivalence"?
2. Am I correct in assuming that such a conjecture should imply that the only sources of $\pi_1$ in the fibers should come from universal Abel map to the relative Picard variety?

Even more vaguely:

1. Does it make sense to try and use Costello's paper [Higher genus Gromov-Witten invariants as genus zero invariants of symmetric products](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v164-n2-p05.pdf) to deduce such a statement from a corresponding genus zero Cohen-Jones-Segal for the product stack $S^{g+1}(X)$?

Is there an example of work in this direction?

2. Are there any results coming from h-principle/Oka theory (i.e., results about the inclusion into the space of differentiable maps $Hol(S_g,N) \to Map(S_g,N)$ being weak homotopy equivalence for certain Stein manifolds $N$ etc), which can be extended to the case of a projective target space?

( This is basically Part B of my previous question: [What is the fundamental group of Kontsevich's space of stable maps?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265144/what-is-the-fundamental-group-of-kontsevichs-space-of-stable-maps) following Jason's extremely helpful suggestions in the comments )

Comment: The fundamental group of $\mathcal{M}_{g,1}$ is nontrivial (it is a mapping class group), and often the fibers of $\text{ev}$ will dominate $\mathcal{M}_{g,1}$ via a forgetful morphism $\Phi$.  So if you want to "factor out" this part of the fundamental group, you should either hold fixed the complex structure on your domain Riemann surface, or perhaps you should consider the product morphism $(\text{ev},\Phi):\mathcal{M}_{g,1}(X,\beta)\to X\times \mathcal{M}_{g,1}.$